# Data Lake North Europe IP Range

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I try to access my Azure SQL Database via U-SQL but I got the following error:

> Internal error! Cannot open server 'testusql' requested by the login.
>   Client with IP address '104.44.91.xx' is not allowed to access the
>   server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or
>   run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall
>   rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five
>   minutes for this change to take effect.

I found an article about IP range in US ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt763307.aspx)), but not in Europe. Where can I find information about the range for North Europe?

I configured the Azure SQL Server firewall to allow access to Azure Services, but it not works (maybe due to the different regions).

Thank you very much.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my apology but I am currently on vacation, so I had not time to update the IP ranges yet. It should be 104.44.91.64/27 for EU North.